# Chained jQuery.then() - is each next one executing only after previous resolve completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, promise, jquery-deferred

I have this code

```
$.when(
    // I checked the first one and assume all return promises
    datacontext.entity1.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity2.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity3.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity4.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity5.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity6.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity7.getPromise({ ...options... }),                    )
.then(
    // some more similar calls returning promises
    datacontext.entity8.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity9.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity10.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity11.getPromise({ ...options... }),                    
)
.then(function() {
    // do work with the results
});
```

If I understand correctly, execution of first `then()` should not start until all defers in the `when()` have been resolved. Is that correct?
Should I expect the same for the two `then()` sections - i.e. `// do work with the results` should not be reached before all calls from preceeding `then()` have resolved? It seems to be true in Chrome, but in FF I am hitting the last `then()` before all defers have been resolved.

So based on the comment, is this the right way to chain things?

```
$.when(
    // I checked the first one and assume all return promises
    datacontext.entity1.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity2.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity3.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity4.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity5.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity6.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity7.getPromise({ ...options... })
)
.then(function() {
    $.when(
        // some more similar calls returning promises
        datacontext.entity8.getPromise({ ...options... }),
        datacontext.entity9.getPromise({ ...options... }),
        datacontext.entity10.getPromise({ ...options... }),
        datacontext.entity11.getPromise({ ...options... })
    )
    .then(function() {
        // do work with the results
    });
})
```

Comment: `.then` accepts two functions, not a list of promises. You have to pass a function, call `when` inside of it, pass the promises to it, and return the return value from `when`. Have a look at the documentation of `.then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery `$.when` (and `Promise.all` in the standard) takes a list of promises and returns a promises that resolves when all of the promises resolve.

The `.then` method signals continuation and accepts a fulfillment and rejection handler. When you a return a promise from a `.then` it will continue on only when the returned promise has resolved. When you return a value, it will continue "immediately".

So, what you want to do is to return a `$.when` from the second then handler:

```
$.when(
    // I checked the first one and assume all return promises
    datacontext.entity1.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity2.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity3.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity4.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity5.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity6.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity7.getPromise({ ...options... }))
.then(function(){ // our handler, note that its params are the resolution values

    return $.when( // which will resolve when this composite promise will resolve
    // some more similar calls returning promises
    datacontext.entity8.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity9.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity10.getPromise({ ...options... }),
    datacontext.entity11.getPromise({ ...options... }),                    
    )
})
.then(function() {
    // do work with the results
});
```

If I may suggest:

1. Use a real promise implementation, jQuery deferred objects are very limited.
2. Pass the data from the promise using the return value rather than using global/closure variables.